# How to resolve ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (230,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 4) in python using Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I can't seem to resolve the issue as I am new to tensorflow I think the issue is the graph mismatching
   but cant resolve it please help. I want to resolve this as i will be using this for android app.

**Defining placeholders:**

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,80,80,3])
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,4])
```

**CNN Layer:**

```
%%time
#Changing settings for GPU running.
config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
config.gpu_options.allocator_type = 'BFC'
#Training and saving the result
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(TRAIN_DIR, graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    for i in range(epochs):
        for j in range(0,steps,step_size):            
            _ , c , summary,d = sess.run([train,cross_entropy,merged_summary_op,acc],feed_dict={x:X[j:j+step_size] , y_true:Y[j:j+step_size] ,hold_prob1:0.5,hold_prob2:0.5,hold_prob3:0.5,hold_prob4:0.5})
            summary_writer.add_summary(summary, i * total_batch + j)
            acc_train.append(d)
            mean_of_cross_entropy = sess.run(cross_entropy,feed_dict={x:cv_x,y_true:cv_y ,hold_prob1:1.0,hold_prob2:1.0,hold_prob3:1.0,hold_prob4:1.0})
            mean_of_acc = sess.run(acc,feed_dict={x:cv_x ,y_true:cv_y ,hold_prob1:1.0,hold_prob2:1.0,hold_prob3:1.0,hold_prob4:1.0})
            cross_entropy_list.append(mean_of_cross_entropy)
            acc_list.append(mean_of_acc)
        print(i,mean_of_cross_entropy,mean_of_acc)
    saver.save(sess, "C:\\Users\\blessie\\Desktop\DATASETS - TOMATO LEAF DISEASE\\Models\\CNN_MC.ckpt")
    print("test accuracy = ",np.mean([sess.run(acc,feed_dict={x:test_x[:230],y_true:test_y[:230] ,hold_prob1:1.0,hold_prob2:1.0,hold_prob3:1.0,hold_prob4:1.0}),sess.run(acc,feed_dict={x:test_x[230:460],y_true:test_y[230:460] ,hold_prob1:1.0,hold_prob2:1.0,hold_prob3:1.0,hold_prob4:1.0}),sess.run(acc,feed_dict={x:test_x[460:],y_true:test_y[460:] ,hold_prob1:1.0,hold_prob2:1.0,hold_prob3:1.0,hold_prob4:1.0})]))   
    print("cross_entropy loss = ",np.mean([sess.run(cross_entropy,feed_dict={x:test_x[:230],y_true:test_y[:230] ,hold_prob1:1.0,hold_prob2:1.0,hold_prob3:1.0,hold_prob4:1.0}),sess.run(cross_entropy,feed_dict={x:test_x[230:460],y_true:test_y[230:460] ,hold_prob1:1.0,hold_prob2:1.0,hold_prob3:1.0,hold_prob4:1.0}),sess.run(cross_entropy,feed_dict={x:test_x[460:],y_true:test_y[460:] ,hold_prob1:1.0,hold_prob2:1.0,hold_prob3:1.0,hold_prob4:1.0})]))
```

After running the code and pre-processing the data, I got a value error stating:

**ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (230,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 4)'**

How can I resolve this problem/error?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given the full code, but from the error message, it appears that your `y_true` placeholder is being supplied with data of shape `[230]` which is basically of type `[None]`. So changing your `y_true` to should solve this particular problem:

```
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None])
```

But you have used `y_true` previously in your code already. So, is the shape of `cv_y` correctly being fed as `[None, 4]`.

Other particular thing what I can guess is you are supplying one hot encoded values to `cv_y` already but in the subsequent lines of code you are not. So, you can change your code as below:

```
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None])
y_true = tf.one_hot(y_true, 4)
```

And now, you will have to change your `cv_y` just before you are passing it in `feed_dict` as

```
cv_y = np.argmax(cv_y, axis=-1)
```